# ng-repeat grouping with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have 2 tables in mysql;

- `items`
- `categories`

`items` have a `cat_id` column point to their category in `categories` table

I use the below query to get items and categories;

```
SELECT a.id, a.cat_id, a.rest_id, a.name, a.description, a.price, b.rest_id, b.name 
FROM items a, categories b 
WHERE a.cat_id = b.id AND b.rest_id = 1
```

I want to use ng-repeat to produce a list like below;

```
Category A

Item (belongs to cat A)
Item (belongs to cat A)
Item (belongs to cat A)

Category B

Item (belongs to cat B)
Item (belongs to cat B)
Item (belongs to cat B)
```

How do I achieve this with `ng-repeat`

I have this so far but isn't working;

```
<div class="results-group" ng-repeat="(key, value) in fetchedData">
   <h3 style="text-align: left;"></h3>
    <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="data in value">
     </li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

Thanks.

---

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE rest_id = $restaurant_id";
$select_all_cats = mysqli_query($connection, $query1);
$rows = $select_all_cats -> num_rows;

$arr1 = array();
$arr2 = array();
if($rows > 0) {
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_cats)) { 
        $arr1[] = $rows;
        $cat_id = $rows['id']; 

        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE cat_id = $cat_id";
        $select_all_items = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
        $rowx = $select_all_items -> num_rows;
        if($rowx > 0) {
            while($rowx = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_items)) {
                $arr2[] = $rowx;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you may use 2 queries to handle this , one to loop for the categories and the other for the items

Comment: How do I then achieve the list I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should remove nested queries in PHP. Looped/nested queries is an anti-pattern that you should learn to recognize and typically replace with an appropriate query that leverages join(s).

Something like this should do the trick on PHP side:

```
// array to store results
$item_array = array();
$query = "SELECT
    cat.name AS cat_name,
    i.id AS id,
    i.name AS name,
    i.description AS description,
    i.price AS price
FROM categories AS cat
INNER JOIN items AS i
    ON cat.id = i.id
WHERE i.rest_id = ?
ORDER BY cat_name ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if($result) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // read into 2D array
        $item_array[$row['cat_name']][] = $row;
    }
}
```

It is important to note that we are building a two-dimensional array here, with the category name being the first dimension.  You could then use this with ng-repeat as follows. Note that I am going to refer to data in `$item_array` above as `itemData` here.  Also note that `itemData`, when formatted for javascript would take the form of an object. Each one of the category "properties" on `itemData` would hold a numerically indexed array of the item records.

```
<div class="results-group" ng-repeat="(cat, items) in itemData">
   <h3 style="text-align: left;">{{cat}}</h3>
    <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="item in items">
         <!-- output content from item here like {{item.name}} and similar -->
     </li>
    <ul>
</div>
```